# OpenGL illumination and shining

Tags: c++, opengl

I have to put illumination in a OpenGL picture but i don't know how to put a correct point light illumination like in the following picture:

[image: Right]

For now i had tried different mode of illumination, but the result is the following :(

[image: Wrong]

I attach you the code that I used for my result.  What is wrong?

```
    float specref[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    // Light values and coordinates
    float ambientLight[] = { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f };
    float diffuseLight[] = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
    float specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    float lightPos[] = { 0.0f, -150.0f, -150.0f, 1.0f };

    glEnable ( GL_LIGHTING ) ;

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,diffuseLight);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPECULAR,specular);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,lightPos);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR,specref);
    glMateriali(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,GL_SHININESS,128);
    glEnable ( GL_COLOR_MATERIAL ) ;

    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
```

Edit 04/11/2011 0.39 CET

I attach also my display() function called by glutDisplayFunc(display);

```
  void display(void)

  {

  [...]

  //Draw polygons in 3d

  glColor3f(0.0,1.0,1.0);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);

  for(i=0;i<NVERT-1;i++) {

        for (j=0;j<NVERT-1;j++) {

              glVertex3f( (GLfloat)((sb[i*NVERT+j]).x()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[i*NVERT+j]).y()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[i*NVERT+j]).z()));


              glVertex3f( (GLfloat)((sb[i*NVERT+j+1]).x()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[i*NVERT+j+1]).y()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[i*NVERT+j+1]).z()));


              glVertex3f( (GLfloat)((sb[(i+1)*NVERT+j+1]).x()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[(i+1)*NVERT+j+1]).y()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[(i+1)*NVERT+j+1]).z()));


              glVertex3f( (GLfloat)((sb[(i+1)*NVERT+j]).x()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[(i+1)*NVERT+j]).y()),

                                      (GLfloat)((sb[(i+1)*NVERT+j]).z()));


        }



  }

  glEnd();
  glFlush();

  }
```

In practice with display I write the small areas that compose the 2° figure that i represented (I omitted the algorithm for the calculation of the points of each area because is it working).

My goal is to have a result similar to figure 1 for the lightning and rendering of the figure but I only obtained the result in figure 2.

I don't know how to put correctly the light and how to setup my figure in order to have this render (like mirror).

Comment: Post a complete, minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Could be several things. I'm guessing you don't have any normals, but wild guess. We need a minimal example as @genpfault points out.

Comment: Is the first image what you want to achieve and the second what you have at the moment?

Comment: I have put other details, i hope that they can be helpful :) thank you very much!

Comment: @larsm Not so wild a guess, it seems.

Comment: I'd suggest you to work with lighting with simple primitives. The lighting source's position the most important point. 

http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl8.htm
http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html

Comment: The lighting source's position is not more important than having normals, and I see no `glNormal3f` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing normals. You either need to provide one normal per vertex ([glNormal](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glNormal.xml)) or you could enable `GL_AUTO_NORMALS` if you use [glMap2](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMap2.xml) (which you are not). There's an article on how to [compute normals for a triangle or polygons](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal) on opengl.org that you probably will find useful.

```
Begin Function CalculateSurfaceNormal (Input Polygon) Returns Vector

   Set Vertex Normal to (0, 0, 0)

   Begin Cycle for Index in [0, Polygon.vertexNumber)

      Set Vertex Current to Polygon.verts[Index]
      Set Vertex Next    to Polygon.verts[(Index plus 1) mod Polygon.vertexNumber]

      Set Normal.x to Sum of Normal.x and (multiply (Current.y minus Next.y) by (Current.z plus Next.z))
      Set Normal.y to Sum of Normal.y and (multiply (Current.z minus Next.z) by (Current.x plus Next.x))
      Set Normal.z to Sum of Normal.z and (multiply (Current.x minus Next.x) by (Current.y plus Next.y))

   End Cycle

   Returning Normalize(Normal)

End Function
```

From the image you posted of the results it seems you are calculating and drawing the normals (red arrows), just not applying them.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really figure out what's happening with your code. I hope your cordinates are between -1 to +1. I'd suggest you to work with lighting with simple primitives. the work on with your surface generation. The lighting source's position and calculating normals are the most important points.

http://www.falloutsoftware.com/tutorials/gl/gl8.htm

http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter05.html

Comment: I don't know why the coordinates should be in [-1,1], unless you mean the normals, which aren't actually there.

Comment: the lighting parameters seems in between -1 to +1 and if the mapping higher value, he won't be able to see the effects. that's what I was confirming

Comment: What lighting parameters are in [-1,1]? I hope you don't mean the colors, which don't have anything to do with any coordinates (and are in [0,1], anyway). And the light's position (the only "lighting parameter" related to coordinates) is (0, -150, -150).